# Проблема с входом Yii2

Tags: yii2

Когда я вхожу на сайт не активным пользователем - вход работает хорошо. То есть, когда я вошел, меня перекидывает на

```
http://site.ru/my
```

и пишет что вы не активированы. Но когда я вхожу как активированный - оно перекидывает на

```
http://site.ru/my
```

и пишет, что доступ запрещен, вам нужно войти. Проверку делаю через

```
Yii::$app->user->isGuest
```

То есть, в первом результате оно возвращает 0, а во втором - 1. Почему?

Comment: метод проверяет, является пользователь гостем или нет.
То-есть если он гость - нам вернётся `true` (1), если же он аутентифицирован - соответственно вернётся `false` (0). А вот без информации о том где, как и для чего у вас это проверяется сложно сказать, где именно вы запутались.

Comment: я знаю, что этот метод делает. суть в том, что когда я логинюсь, в базе для этого пользователя `status=10`, то есть он не активный. этот метод возвращает 0 после того, как я залогинюсь. я не выхожу с системы, а просто в базе меняю ему `status=13`, то есть делаю активным, перегружаю страницу и этот метод возвращает 1. вот я не могу понять, почему?

Comment: в модели User есть метод `findIdentity`, где идёт поиск пользователя с указанным статусом, поменяв в БД `status` на '13', поменяйте его и в методе, и затем поймёте как это работает

Comment: этот метод у меня такой `public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne($id);
    }`

Comment: Метод `isGuest` - говорит гость или не гость, и ему все равно что у вас там в базе, 10 или 13, пользователь или авторизовался или нет. А сообщение - "доступ запрещен" значит что пользователь авторизовался (isGuest вернет 0) но у него нет прав на действие. Смотрим в сторону контроля доступа.